# C++ fork() access methods of parent and vice versa

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have 2 objects like this:

```
clientsService clserver = clientsService(&clientServerFD,portclientsrv);
techniciansService techserver = techniciansService(&techServerFD,porttechsrv);
```

it constructs everything necessary to bind and listen to local ports.
So to do multithreading I just used `fork()` before to to call the object method that calls `accept()` and holds. So I can do two `accept()` one for clserver and another to techserver.
Problem is: I need that techserver, which also forks right after accept returns a connection fd, checks clserver instance to return a clients fd.

Objective of the program is a chat-like tech support. I know, I will secure the things later but for now I must put this to work.

**Question**: *How can an instance talks to another one in other process?*

**The server object and techserver object can be referenced cross fork()? A change on techserver object in child will be noticed on server object from the parent?**

I though about signals but it isn't clear how I can return a value of clients fd.
After I check that there is a client holding and waiting for a technician to connect so it acts like a tcp proxy after that.
Is using fork() the right approach or I'm just stuck here because I'm not using the right functions and programming logic?

Code as an example how I'm starting the service program:

```
   if(fork()==0){
        //SERVICE THAT ACCEPTS Clients
        while(1){
            int client = server.startService(sockfd); //holds on accept()
            if(fork()==0){
                server.waitForTechnician(client); //holds in loop asking techserver if there is any technician FD to connect to.
                shutdown(client,2); //when done talking clients shutdowns.
                exit(0);
            }else continue;
        }
    }
    else{
        //SERVICE THAT ACCEPTS TECH
        while(1){
            int tecnico = techserver.startService(techfd); //holds on accept()
            if(fork()==0){
                techserver.initWork(tecnico); //start to work to later, check in a loop if in server object is a client FD available to connect to.
                shutdown(tecnico,2);
                exit(0);//disconnected
            }else continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use threads instead of forking processes. Forking is so 1980s.

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/ or http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: @EJP: There is nothing wrong with forking, _per se_, if used carefully it helps isolating the different tasks and avoids a lot of races. It is not clear what the OP wants to do with their tasks, so it is not clear what would be better.

Comment: The server object and techserver object can be referenced cross fork()? A change on techserver object in child will be noticed on server object from the parent?

Comment: 100% agree with @rodrigo. Forking is extremely useful in a lot of scenarios.

Comment: @knivil http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/pipes.html I think this will work at 4.2. "fork() and pipe()—you have the power!".
That's what I think I need.